# Merging multiple data frames without getting duplicates

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge 6+ datasets into one by ID. Right now, the duplication of IDs makes merge treat each as a new observation.

Example code:

```
combined <-Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all=TRUE), list(NRa,NRb,NRc,NRd,NRe,NRf,NRg,NRh))
```

Which gives me this:

```
        ID Segment.h Segment.g Segment.f Segment.e Segment.d Segment.c
1 62729107        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        1
2 62734839        NA         1        NA        NA        1         NA
3 62734839        NA        NA        NA        1         NA        NA
4 62737229        NA        1         NA        NA        NA        NA
5 62737229        NA        NA        NA        1         1         NA
```

I would like each ID to have a single row:

```
         ID Segment.h Segment.g Segment.f Segment.e Segment.d Segment.c
1 62729107        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        1
2 62734839        NA        1         NA        1         1         NA
3 62737229        NA        1         NA        1         1         NA
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: since you're not specifying `by`, this is merging by the intersection of pairwise data frames' column names

Answer (score 1):

Using R's sqldf package will work leaving you with one id per row.

```
Data1 <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Housing = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
Data2 <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Credit = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
Data3 <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  OwnsCar = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
Data4 <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  CollegeGrad = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

library(sqldf)
sqldf("Select Data1.X,Data1.Housing,Data2.Credit,Data3.OwnsCar,Data4.CollegeGrad from Data1 
      inner join Data2 on Data1.X = Data2.X
      inner join Data3 on Data1.X = Data3.X
      inner join Data4 on Data1.X = Data4.X
      ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `by='ID'` in your `merge()` function. If that's not enough, try `aggregate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is not entirely clear, and you don't provide data.

Assuming that all of your dataframes have the same dimensions, column names, column orders, ID entries, that the ID row orders match, that ID is the first column, that all other entries are either NA or 1 and that any cell in one dataframe featuring a 1 has NA values in that cell for all other data frames or that sums of numeric values are acceptable, and that you want the result as a data frame ...

An Old-School solution using the abind package:

```
consolidate <- function(lst) {

    stopifnot(require(abind))

    ## form 3D array, replace NA
    x <- abind(lst, along=3)
    x[is.na(x)] <- 0

    z <- x[,,1] ## data store

    ## sum array along 3rd dimension
    for (j in seq(2,ncol(x)))
        for (i in seq(nrow(x)))
            z[i,j] <- sum(x[i,j,])

    z[z==0] <- NA ## restore NA

    as.data.frame(z)
}
```

For dataframes (with the above caveats) a,b,c:

```
consolidate(list(a,b,c))
```